# Move file, change permissions and rename it keeping the same extesion

Tags: permissions, cron, zsh, rsync, mv

Using zsh 5.2 on Fedora 24 workstation.

I want to be programatically able to:

- move an image file (can have jpg/ jpeg/ png/ JPG/ PNG extensions)
  from /tmp/folder1 to ~/Pictures
- This file will have the same few initial characters --- prefix111.jpg OR prefix222.png, etc.
- rename the file such that samefilename.JPG becomes 20161013.jpg
- 20161013 is today's date in yyyymmdd format
- Note that the extension becomes small letters
- And JPEG or jpeg becomes jpg
- change the permissions of the moved file to 644

All at one go.

If there are multiple prefix* files, the command should just fail silently.

I will initially like to do it at the command prompt with an option to add a cron job later. I mean, will the same zsh command/ script work in cron?

I am sure, this is doable. However, with my limited shell knowledge, could only achieve:

```
mv /tmp/folder1/prefix-*.JPG ~/Pictures/$(date +'%Y%m%d').jpg
```

Problems with my approach are many. It does not handle capitalization, does not take care of different extensions and does not address the permission issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
#!/bin/sh
FILES="/tmp/folder1/prefix*.jpg /tmp/folder1/prefix*.jpeg /tmp/folder1/prefix*.png h/tmp/folder1/prefix*.JPG /tmp/folder1/prefix*.PNG"
if [ $(ls $FILES | wc -l ) -gt 1 ]; then
    exit 1
fi
if [ $(ls $FILES | grep -i '\.png$') ]; then
  SUFF=png
else
  SUFF=jpg
fi
DEST=$HOME/Pictures/$(date +'%Y%m%d').$SUFF
mv $FILES $DEST
chmod 644 $DEST
```